# XY-problem question and a lot of upvotes... should I change my accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

[My question in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regex-for-accented-characters-diacritics).

I asked the above question nearly *6 years ago* (when I was just a wee lad on SO). I was trying to create a regex for faculty names, which could have accented characters like *é*. So I tried to capture them in a regex to validate the input. Well, turns out the only thing I *actually* needed was to capture `last_name, first_name`. Now, the question has over 120 upvotes and the answers on it as well. However, my accepted answer, while it solves my problem, might obscure the actual answers from people who *really need a JavaScript regex for diacritics*.

Should I change my accepted answer to [Maycow Moura's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26900132/1986871)?

Comment: Generally, if it helped you find the solution, you accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not look like accepted answer actually answers the question *as asked*, so it would beneficial for community to switch accepted answer to one by Maycow Moura.

While there is no obligation to change acceptance mark as it only says "it helped original poster the most" moving acceptance to the answer that is the most useful currently is very nice gesture from OP. Problem of obsolete highly-upvoted answers showing above currently most useful answer is one frequently discussed on meta without much success - while it is not exactly the case here, it is nice of you as original poster to maintain the best answer on top.

Theoretical side benefit: moving the best answer closed to the question may bring in some extra votes on the question too as people will still see both question and answer on the same page rather than scroll down so question is no longer visible.